# New columns in uploaded excel file not showing in data module

Tags: cognos-11

I've uploaded an excel file and created a data module that uses it. I've now replaced this file after adding two new columns to my excel file, but my new columns are not showing up in my data module.

I know they are there because if I remove them Cognos complains, but even after refreshing properties and re-linking the excel file, the two columns do not show in the columns listed. The data in the existing files has been updated as well.

Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you see the new columns in the sources tree?  In order releases you would need to drag the entire table into the data module to add the new columns.  In newer (last 2 years or so ) releases you can just drag the new columns to add them to the data module as well as the old method.

Comment: I found it in the source tree. It wasn't immediately evident, but I was able to drag the new columns into the module. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you modify a data source to add or remove columns you need to manually add the columns to the data module tree from the sources tree.

You need to expand the sources pane but pressing the sources button, which is on the left margin [image: sources button]

In older releases you would need to drag the entire table into the data module to add the new columns. In newer (last 2 years or so ) releases you can just drag the new columns to add them to the data module as well as the old method.

This is what the sources pane looks like once expanded into view.
[image: expanded sources pane]